# Editing without bringing question up

Tags: feature-request, questions, editing, answers

Is there a way to edit a question or answer without bringing it to the top of the list of questions? Sometimes I notice that I made a mistake in a question or answer (spelling, etc.) but don't fix it since that would bring the post up to the top of the list (although the question was already answered and would not serve a purpose by being seen by the members of this site again).

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/789/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature doesn't exist.

Nor, seemingly, will it. [Jeff Atwood](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/484/jeff-atwood) tagged [a nearly identical question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483) on Meta Stack Overflow [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). The comments on [yet another, even more nearly identical, question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74401) also are strongly against the suggestion.